# Duda con validación de datos en ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo una tabla llamada *Charla* que va así:

```
create table charla (
    id_charla, 
    inicio_charla,
    fin_charla,
    estado
)
```

Bueno lo que quiero es que haga una verificación entre el campo **fin_charla** y el **sysdate** ya que, si este último es mayor a **fin_charla** entonces, el estado que por default es 1 pase a 0, estaba viendo sobre el uso de JOB pero nose si me resultará, espero su experiencia pueda guiarme. Gracias!

Adjunto el avance de mi procedure:

```
create or replace procedure validar(
    v_id_charla in charla.id_charla%type,
    obtenerFin out DATE
)
is
begin
    select fin_charla into obtenerFin from charla where id_charla = v_id_charla;
    if(obtenerFin < sysdate) then
        update charla set estado = 0 where id_charla = v_id_charla;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con un trigger

Comment: @pablomatico los triggers pueden hacer la verificación de datos ya ingresados en una tabla para realizar el update en caso cumpla la condición y que se ejecute día por día en una fecha determinada?

Comment: los triggers son disparados por un determinado evento, podrías hacer que se ejecutara cada vez que fin_charla sea modificado y en ese momento hacer la comprobación y la actualización si es necesaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo unico que podrias hacer es poner un [check](http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/oracleya/simulador/simulador.php?cod=201&punto=2&inicio=)

```
 create table charla(
  fecha date,
  estado char(1),
constraint fkfa  Check (estado='0' or estado='1'));
```

y No, no puede usar sysdate en restricciones de verificación.

¿Por qué?

Todas las filas en una tabla para una restricción habilitada deben devolver verdadero para su expresión.

Pero sysdate no es determinista. Puede obtener un resultado diferente cada vez que lo llame. Entonces, el resultado (verdadero / falso) puede (cambiará) con el tiempo. Entonces Oracle no puede garantizar que la expresión sea siempre cierta para cada fila.

Ver:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52205

y no creo q sea necesario que uses un job y deberias llenar todos los campos de tu table con un procedimiento que haga algo asi

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE registrar
    (
        id_charla int, 
        inicio_charla int,
        fin_charla date,
    )
    IS 
    ESTADO CHAR(2);
    begin 
    if registrar>sysdate then 
    estado :=0;
    else 
estado:=1;
    end if;
    insert into charla values(  id_charla,    inicio_charla,    fin_charla,    estado);
    UPDATE charla SET estado = (CASE WHEN fin_charla < SYSDATE THEN '0' ELSE '1' END) ;
    END registrar;
```

Comment: Hola, y en caso se solicite que el proceso de verificación del campo **fin_charla** cambie su estado si es menor al sysdate, y que este se repita cada día a un determinada hora y que verifique los datos

Comment: entonces tendrias que usar un job "que este se repita cada día a un determinada hora", esa es su finalidad pero igual, puedes dejar que el job use el procedimiento

Comment: entiendo, pero tengo una duda ... este job que crearé verificará data que ya ha sido ingresada antes sin la ejecucion del procedure?

Comment: no, asi como esta el procedimiento solo modificaria nuevos registros tendrias que modificar el procedimiento, pues no tienes valores de entrada y seria un update

Comment: actualicé mi post, añadiendo un procedure que creé pero no cumple la función que quiero porque no verifica los campos que ya están en la tabla

Comment: HOLA,  POR FAVOR USA `UPDATE charla SET estado = (CASE WHEN  fin_charla < SYSDATE THEN '0' ELSE '1' END) ;`

Comment: Disculpa, nose si aun te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedó perfecto.